# How to disable angle bracket highlighting in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just want to disable the character highlighting that happens on angle brackets, as I find the square box to be annoying. Is there a way to turn it off?

[image]

Comment: Rather than turn it off, per se, is there a way to change the style for the box-shaped highlight so that the box is the same colour as the background?  That would render it, for all intents and purposes, invisible, and certainly less annoying.  Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Just make the color customization transparent ala :     "editorBracketMatch.border": "#ff000000",
Note the two extra 00 at the end of the color.

Comment: Finally found someone asking the right question. The default looks horrific.Now all I need is to disable the 100ms delay tooltip which tells me what a <span> is.

Comment: Thank you so very much for that question. I do not understand how not more people are annoyed by that. You can hardly see the cursor when the box is shown, so it's hard to determine whether I'm right or left of the character.

Comment: @MSOACC "editor.hover.enabled": false.

You're welcome.

Answer (score 27):

You can search keyword `highlight` in setting, and you change `Editor:Match Bracket` to `never`, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 17):

You can use the following:
`// Highlight matching brackets when one of them is selected.
  "editor.matchBrackets": false,` however it disables highlighting all the brackets not only the angle brackets.

Comment: I'd just like it for the angle brackets only, because the box in particular is annoying.

Comment: Saved me from installing a plugin.

Comment: false works, but valid. "editor.matchBrackets": "never",

Answer (score 15):

You can always make the bracket border color transparent with these settings:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    "editorBracketMatch.border": "#0000",
    "editorBracketMatch.background": "#000"
}
```

This will make the border transparent and the bracket's background black - or just make it something less obtrusive given your editor background.  But again, this will apply to all brackets, not just angle brackets.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it's still unconfigurable. Maybe they will improved it.

Here is my ticket in VSCode repo that you can watch - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73521.

As long as they do not improve, you have two ways

#### Solution with addon:

1. Disable native bracket matching: `"editor.matchBrackets": false,`
2. Install addon from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rafamel.subtle-brackets
3. Customize it for better visuality, example:

```
    "subtleBrackets.style": {
        "borderStyle": "solid",
        "borderColor": "#CC7832",
        "borderRadius": "3px",
    }
```

[image]
[image]

#### Native solution without addon:

- You can disable bracket matching highlight **only** for specific language:

```
"[html]": {
   "editor.matchBrackets": false
}
```

Note that this is not a perfect solution, because when using html in php files, angle brackets are still highlighted

Comment: all these solutions  are based on the assumption people work using a single theme. If you switch between a dark and a light one, all these plugins introducing colours are simply a mess.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this

```
{
  "editor.matchBrackets": "near"
}
```

somewhere in ~/.config/Code/User/settings.json. This means that all projects inherit behavior.

This way, only when you move the cursor over a bracket, the corresponding one is shown.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Yaa. there is a solution for hiding the annoying marking I just found. go to the setting button in left bottom side then write- angle bracket -in the search option and search as well. Then press the "text editor", a selecting option will come in the top named "Editor:Match Brackets". Select "Never" and your work is done here. See the attached picture if needed.

[image]